# Order by Date PHP

Tags: php

I have looked all over for this and have not found an answer. What I have in my table is a month row, a day row, and a year row all separate. It gets the month, day, and year from a form. That way I can display the date as Month Day, Year (ex: August 5, 2011). Is there anyway that I can take this information and organize it by date?

Comment: I'm assuming you are using a database, since you mention table rows.  If that's the case, just wondering why you are storing each value in it's own column (month, day and year).  It would be more efficient, and easier to sort if you used DATETIME or even TIMESTAMP.

Comment: @producerism: ordering through 3 fields covered by index as efficient as ordering by one field (the difference is negligible)

Comment: it seems 1 DATETIME column is better than 3 columns, with the added benefit of being able to also store hours/minutes/seconds along with the date.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$date1 = "August 5, 2011"; 
$date2 = "August 1, 2011"; 

$result = strtotime($date1); 
$result2 = strtotime($date2); 

$results = array($result, $result2); 
asort($results); 
print_r($results); 
?>
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/09b7e.php